# Declaring an array in Perl catalyst template

Tags: perl, catalyst

I need to declare an array in my Perl catalyst template file like we declare it in our Perl 
eg: @array = (1..100);
Can someone help me with that
[% $array = (1..100)%]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[% a = [0..8] %]
[% a.5 %]
will print 5.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Template Toolkit, you can initialize an array like this:

```
[% myarray = [ 1 .. 100 ] %]
```

OR

```
[% x=1
   y=100
   myarray = [ x..y ] %]
```

For more info on arrays and TT (Template Toolkit) you can have a look here:

http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Variables.html#section_List_References